# Как отловить вставку из буфера и изменить вставляемые данные?

Tags: android, javascript, ios

Доброго времени суток!

Вопрос таков: есть в браузере любое поле для ввода. Надо при вставке в него данных из буфера, взять эти данные, форматировать по своему усмотрению и только затем вставить их в поле для ввода.

Событие onpaste на андроиде не срабатывает. oninput не дает доступа к данным в буфере. window.clipboardData не реализовано из-за политики безопасности.

Comment: >> реализовано из-за политики безопасности

это ключевое

Comment: Да, но в Сафари ведь onpaste срабатывает, и там можно получить к данным, которые ставятся в поле. Я полагаю, что есть какой-то способ из буффера сразу вставить в поле ввода отформатированные данные.

Comment: Вставить в поле просто. Никто не мешает почистить поле и вставить что нужно.

Comment: я бы попробовал вставить из буфера в поле, потом взять оттуда текст, отформатировать как нужно и вставить обратно

Comment: @Роман Захаров,  @KoVadim, определенно, то что вы говорите, единственный способ. Тут уж ничего не поделать. Кто-нить, переделайте свой комментарий в ответ, я его приму как правильный.

Answer (score 1):

Вот, посмотрите, как можно заблокировать вставку в текстовое поле.
Работает через bind

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327129/how-to-disable-paste-in-android-browser-using-jquery

Пример из ответа по ссылке (вторым способом реально менять данные)
http://jsfiddle.net/BHaab/